# Is it possible to migrate WinJS app to C#/XAML WinRT and vice versa

Tags: windows-runtime, migration, winjs

I've developed and published a Javascript WinJS app for Windows Store. Reasons aside, is it possible to upload next release of this app written entirely in C#/WinRT/XAML instead? How to migrate an IndexedDB database data in such scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd just associate your C#/XAML code with the existing app in the store, and then upload the `.appxupload` just as before, it's essentially language agnostic at that point.

IndexedDB will be tougher, and perhaps the closest analog would be SQLite, though they are far from identical.